# Remove job after it is complete in Node Bull is not working

Tags: node.js

I am using node bull for scheduling. Now for my jobs i pass a cron time to it (which is a specific time and a date). Now since i have provided a strict cron then it must run for only one time or even if it run second time then it must be removed from the queue (i have provided removeOnComplete: true).

But still it doesn't get removed and it runs again and my queue process this job again. So i want to stop this.

My add job function: (data is my job data, timings is my cron timing)

```
public async addJob(data: any, timings: any, jobId: any) {
    console.log('adding job');
    console.log(timings);
    const job = await this.videoQueue.add(
      {data: data},
      {
        repeat: {
          cron: timings,
        },
        jobId: jobId,
        removeOnComplete: true,
     },
    );
  return job;
}
```

My process function:

```
this.videoQueue.process(async (job: any) => {
    // processing function for my job.
});
```

I am new node and node bull. Maybe i am making a mistake but i am not able to debug it.

Thanks.

Comment: probably show how your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) package to schedule with cron time. It's very easy to use actually

```
    const schedule = require('node-schedule');

    const job = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * *', function(){
        console.log('Job runned.');
        job.cancel();
    });
```